# Configure docker run to use ssl / https / tls

Tags: docker, ssl, https, docker-run

Is there a way to configure docker run to use https? Something like:

```
docker run --https --certs xyz  myimage
```

or do you have to configure that stuff within a Dockerfile/image? *Likewise for TLS.*

```
 docker run --tls --certs xyz  myimage
```

One advantage is we wouldn't have to copy the certs to the image - I'd rather avoid having the certs in the image and/or running container.

Although I guess the best practice is to use the `-v` option to share the certs from the host into the container.

**Update**: after some research I found this:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

it says to start the docker domain with something like this:

```
 dockerd --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem \
   --tlscert=server-cert.pem --tlskey=server-key.pem \
   -H=0.0.0.0:2376
```

is this the right thing to do to secure all containers on the machine?

Answer (score 3):

The `dockerd` tls options are for configuring the daemon to listen on a network port instead of, or in addition to, docker.sock. This is for docker API requests, not to reach your application, and I don't believe what you are asking for.

It sounds like you are looking for TLS termination and forwarding the request to your application in HTTP. For that, there are various reverse proxies that can run in front of your container. Examples include nginx, traefik, haproxy, and I believe most, if not all, feature TLS termination. They do tend to focus on layer 7 and the HTTP protocol, so if you have other types of protocols, you may be forced mounting the TLS credentials into your container, preferably as a secret, or at the worst, a read only volume.

Comment: "tls termination"?

Comment: "TLS termination" means when some server inbetween you and the target will act as a target server for TLS connection. For example, you set up a TLS terminator in your home network on the router, so everyone connects through HTTPS/TLS to this router, then the router sees clear, unencrypted traffic, so it can analyze it or forward to some place that doesn't run HTTPS - your case. In corporate environments this traffic is analyzed for threats/misuse and later encrypted again and forwarded to the destination server.